# Excel creating a pivot tablet

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, pivot-table, countif

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A75kd.png)I'm trying to create a pivot table so that I can make a Chart to show how many of each item is on the report. However since some are missing multiple we seperate them in the same cell by a comma an example is we are missing item 10266 on one row and then another we are missing 10266, 10160 so when I go to do a count it registers them as two different counts for the item number because there is another number in the cell. I just need to have a pivot table count how many times the same number is in the chart. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

Please try to use Power Query.

1. Choose the table, right-click it > Get Data from Table/Range > change the data in "SHORTAGES" column as text.

[image]

2. Click "Split Column" > By Delimiter > Select Comma as the delimiter, and choose "Each occurrence of the delimiter" > OK. I get mutltiple columns as "SHORTAGES1", "SHORTAGES2", "SHORTAGES3".

[image]

3. Remove other columns, just keep these 3 columns.

[image]

4. Do unpivoted for these 3 columns via clicking Transform tab > Unpivot Columns > Unpivot Columns.

[image]

5. Use "Group By" to get the count number.

[image]

6. Click File > Close & Load, the data could be load to one worksheet.

Comment: I've added a picture of some data

Comment: I've tried what you said @Emily and it tells me the Data source reference is not valid.